# In Python, if I have a unix timestamp, how do I insert that into a MySQL datetime field?

Tags: python, mysql, database, datetime, date

I am using Python MySQLDB, and I want to insert this into DATETIME field in Mysql .  How do I do that with cursor.execute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert from a UNIX timestamp to a Python datetime object, use `datetime.fromtimestamp()` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp)).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(0)
datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 1, 0)
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1268816500)
datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 17, 10, 1, 40)
```

From Python datetime to UNIX timestamp:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.mktime(datetime(2010, 3, 17, 10, 1, 40).timetuple())
1268816500.0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the FROM_UNIXTIME MySQL function:

```
#import MySQLdb as mysql
import mysql.connector as mysql

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cnx = mysql.connect(user='root')
    cur = cnx.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)", (1268811665,))
    print cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    cnx.close()
```

The output (if you save the above to epoch.py):

```
$ python epoch.py 
[(datetime.datetime(2010, 3, 17, 8, 41, 5),)]
```

You can use the FROM_UNIXTIME in your INSERT or other DML SQL statements.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

I just did this:

datetime.datetime.now() ...insert that into the column.