# How can you convert datetime.date from mysql into unix timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, datetime

Have spent a few hours trying to figure this out unsuccessfully.

I've imported some 'date' (not datetime) fields from MySQL into a python list. If I print the list, the values will show up as:

```
my_list = [[100, datetime.date(2013, 3, 11)], [101, datetime.date(2013, 4, 13,)],[102,datetime.date(2013, 4, 13)]
```

(...where 101, 102, 103 are my corresponding event_id's, you can disregard them)

I've found that the following will get the conversion correct:

```
unix_time = time.mktime(datetime.date(2009,2,17).timetuple())
```

However, if I try to do something like:

```
for x in my_list:
    x[1] = time.mktime(datetime.date(x[1]).timetuple())
```

It will not work.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can convert the date in mysql: `select unix_timestamp(your_date)`.

Comment: you want to have some validations before sending to mysql.. there's a mysql drive in Python. but simple solution in python: see this for conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460491/in-python-if-i-have-a-unix-timestamp-how-do-i-insert-that-into-a-mysql-datetim

Answer (score 3):

First solution was ugly, new edit:

```
for x in my_list:
  x[1] = time.mktime(x[1].timetuple())
```

should get you your list. No need to wrap the datetime.date in another datetime.date